# X-Rate-Limit with two restrictions?

Tags: limit, rate, rate-limiting

I have a "search" endpoint in my API that requires quite a lot of work in the backend.

For that reason, I've added a Rate limit per minutes (10 req/m) but I also would like to add a rate limit per day to avoid abuse.

The issue I'm facing is regarding the X-Rate-Limit headers. Which one do I display? Is there a technique to display two "values" like in my case?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with the X-Rate-Limit header is limited to working with the League of Legends API.

According to their [documentation here](https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/rate-limiting), rate limits are comma-separated and use the same unit of time. For instance, a rate limit of 100 calls per minute, and 500 calls per hour would be
`X-Rate-Limit-Count: 100:1,500:60` if minutes are your unit of time

They use seconds as their unit of time. I don't know whether or not this is standard practice or if any unit of time is acceptable. If seconds are preferred, the above example would look like `X-Rate-Limit-Count: 100:60,500:3600`.

Comment: v interesting. I sure wouldn't expect that if I were a consumer, but /shrug